# Saving captured frames to separate folders

Tags: python, file, path

Currently working on extracting frames from videos and have noticed that the images get overwritten. Would be nice to create a folder for each of the captured frames but I'm unsure how to do that.

```
data_folder = r"C:\Users\jagac\Downloads\Data"
sub_folder_vid = "hmdb51_org"
path2videos = os.path.join(data_folder, sub_folder_vid)

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path2videos):
    for name in files:
        vids = os.path.join(path, name)

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vids)
        i = 0
        
        frame_skip = 10
        frame_count = 0

        while(cap.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == False:
                break
            
            if i > frame_skip - 1:
                frame_count += 1
                
                path2store= r"C:\Users\jagac\OneDrive\Documents\CSC578\final\HumanActionClassifier\images"
                os.makedirs(path2store, exist_ok= True)
                path2img = os.path.join(path2store, 'test_' + str(frame_count*frame_skip) + ".jpg")
                cv2.imwrite(path2img, frame)
                
                i = 0
                continue
            i += 1 
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre]. on this site we expect you to have debugged your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not incorporating `name` into your path, so each video is overwriting the previous. You can either add the file name to `path2img`, or add `name` to the `path2store` variable before you make the directory.